# jQuery dynamic date and Cufon?

Tags: jquery, cufon

I am using jquery to print the date (month) in to a div on a static page, and want to use Cufon to style the font for that date (I have to use Cufon due to the license of the font.) Even though I have the div before the scripts, and the date script before the cufon script, it won't apply the font to the date. It works everywhere else on the page. Can anybody tell me why this is happening, and if there is a solution?

Comment: Was the down vote really necessary? If you want me to paste the 3000 lines of standard Cufon/jQuery code and an empty div I'm happy to, but I don't think it will help. Clearly my description was enough for somebody to help without any trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I can say with what you made us **assume** is, each and every second, I **assume** that some `DIV`'s html contents get updated. So, in that update request, add this code:

```
Cufon.refresh();
```

Hopefully it should work, if not, please try posting some code so that we can give you better answers. :)

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. Thanks for your help. Sorry I didn't post the code, I didn't think it was necessary as it was more of a logic question than asking for actual code. Cheers.